# Creating threads in for loop: all threads passed same "i" value

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Using the advice found here ([How to spawn n threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964142/how-to-spawn-n-threads)) I wrote the following:

```
int threads_count = 2;
pthread_t *threads = calloc(threads_count, sizeof(pthread_t));
int j;
for(j = 0; j < threads_count; j++) {
    int thread_number = j;
    int status = pthread_create(&threads[j], NULL, &my_func, (void *) &thread_number);
}
```

The relevant portion of `my_func` is as such:

```
void *my_func(void *thread) {
    int *thread_no = (int *) thread;
    pthread_t thread_id = pthread_self();
    printf("Thread number: %i\nThread ID: %u\n", *thread_no, thread_id);

    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, for reasons I don't understand, this has the effect that every thread has the Thread Number (not ID) 2.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Following the answer's advice, I made a global array of corresponding ints and passed references as &arr[i] from within the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
for(j = 0; j < threads_count; j++) {
    int thread_number = j;
    int status = pthread_create(&threads[j], NULL, &my_func, (void *) &thread_number);
}
```

You send to `my_func`, as the `void*` parameter, the address of a local variable which is defined only inside the scope of the given `for` loop. Once you leave that `for` loop, the access to the address of `thread_number` leads to *undefined behavior*!

You can do the same with

```
for(j = 0; j < threads_count; j++) {
    int thread_number = j;
    int status = pthread_create(&threads[j], NULL, &my_func, (void *) thread_number);
}
```

(passing the value of `thread_number` as `void*`) and then dereference it like this:

```
void *my_func(void *thread) {
    int thread_no = (int)thread;
    pthread_t thread_id = pthread_self();
    printf("Thread number: %i\nThread ID: %u\n", thread_no, thread_id);

    ...
}
```

However **this is not the best method** since messing between `int` and `void*` is not recommended (not only `int` with `void*` but any kind of pointers with non pointer types).

The better way would be to use some global structure for each thread and pass the address of that structure to `my_func` as the `void*` argument.